# How do parents give their offspring a chromosome?

Tags: genetics, chromosome

Whenever an organism sexually reproduces, it gives its offspring one chromosome from each of its pairs of chromosomes. My questions are

- Is this done randomly?
- Is it uniformly random?
- If so, what mechanism allows it to be random, considering that the laws of physics are deterministic?

(Note: I'm a little rusty on this subject, so if there are any errors in the question, feel free to correct them.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are the laws of physics deterministic? I think no one knows, currently.

In any event, yes, the segregation of homologous chromosomes during [meiosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiosis) I is random: there is an equal probability for each chromosome of a homologous pair to segregate into a given gamete, and this is independent of other homologous pairs. This idea dates back to [Mendel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mendelian_inheritance), who observed that the heritable “factors” (what we now know as genes) responsible for macroscopic phenotypes are inherited independently of one another (this is his [Law of Independent Assortment](https://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/principle-of-independent-assortment-302)). This isn’t actually true when considering [linked genes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_linkage), but is certainly true of chromosomes, as was described by [Sutton in 1903](http://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/pdfplus/10.2307/1535741):

> ...many points were discovered which strongly indicate that the position of the bivalent chromosomes in the equatorial plate of the reducing division is purely a matter of chance - that is, that any chromosome pair may lie with maternal or paternal chromatid indifferently toward either pole irrespective of the positions of other pairs...